# How to extract files from subfolders which share directory?

Tags: r

I would like to extract data from a directory which is comprised of subfolders with files in question, where the directory has the following structure beginning with some folderValue and going folderN values.

```
    mydir/folder1/car.someformat.gz or bz2
    mydir/folder2/car.someformat.gz or bz2
    mydir/folder3/car.someformat.gz or bz2
    mydir/folder4/car.someformat.gz or bz2
    mydir/folder5/car.someformat.gz or bz2
    mydir/folder6/car.someformat.gz or bz2
    mydir/folder7/car.someformat.gz or bz2
    mydir/folderN/car.someformat.gz or bz2
```

I would like to loop over `mydir/folders` adjust the file to `car.someformat` (`.json` for instance) and save the `car.someformat` in one a common directory.
Therefore I have tried to use `unzip` which supports different archives.

What I tried

```
# First define the directory
path = "mydir"

# Define the set of file and loop over 
lapply(c('car.someformat.gz'),function(x){
sources.files  <- list.files(path=path,
                           recursive=T,
                           pattern=paste('*folder*',x,'*.gz',sep='')
                           ,full.names=T)
  # Call unzip (not sure whether is a better approach)
  dat <- do.call(unzip,sources.files),
  # save file to common directory
     save(dat)})
```

But that doesn't seem quite appropriate.

Comment: Try using the `gzfile` connection

Comment: I would like to use a generic approach which matches not only `gz` archives

Comment: Shouldn't the vector over which you're running `lapply` be `seq(N)` and the `car.someformat.gz` bit be inside the function?

Comment: Maybe `list.dirs` would be helpful here.

Comment: Might be helpful to use `basename` or `dirname` to split the path. `basename` could than be split via regex like `'car\\.([^\\.]+)\\.gz'`... This `gz` could be an argument and combined by `paste0`

Comment: @Mamba It's not at all clear from your question that you're interested in more than `.gz` files. Could you please modify your question to explain?